# Bash command to exit from TL1 terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that telnets to a system's TL1 terminal and executes a command but how do I exit out of the TL1 terminal?

I've tried quit and exit and it doesn't work. Normally, I would press CTRL+C if I had logged in manually to the TL1 term and this would work; but how would I automate this process?

```
    #!/bin/bash 
    (
       echo "ACT-USER::ROOT:D::ROOT;"
       echo "^C"
       echo "quit"
       echo "exit"
    ) | telnet 192.168.1.1

    echo "done"
    exit
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "TL1 terminal"? Is it some piece of hardware?

Comment: @duskwuff TL1 is a protocol for network device management

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect), a tool to script interactive programs that's part of most Linux distributions may help. Some fiddling will be required, but basically it goes like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet 192.168.1.1
send "ACT-USER::ROOT:D::ROOT;\r"
send \003
```

Which will start telnet to the host and send your command string followed by control-c. expect has many more possibilities (especially the fact that it can react to what the other side replies, the possibility to limit the script runtime, etc), and there are literally hundreds of good references on the internet, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks I found a workaround which is to run my block of code as a separate process and then kill the process after a timeout but this expect solution much better and will work also. I'll try this for a more complex script next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the answer is still relevant, and it could be system specific as well, but I use

> echo "logoff;"

command in my case and it works because it is supported on my terminals. If it also doesn't work, you need need to look into your device documentation for related command to logout,